# I could've if I wanted

Tags: conditional-constructions

> I could've if I wanted to.

Aside from figuring out its meaning, is this grammatically correct?

Or it should be only: I could if I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

'Could have' tells that one was capable of doing something but chose not to since it talks about an event that had already happened. So...

**I could've if I wanted to...** is not correct.

**I could have if I had wanted to...** is correct.

I could if I wanted to... is also correct because could refers to simple past, present or future depending on how you use it.